# Javascript Closures: Saving and Restoring Text

Tags: javascript, closures

I am very new to javascript, and am to write a page that has a text area where a user can type in some text.  The context needs to be stored in a local variable in a closure.  When this closure is called, the text area is reverted back to that saved state.  Also, when the user presses the "save" button, a new button appears that shows the timestamp of the saved data.  When the button is pressed, the function for this save point is called, and the text is restored.

I'm stumped on this.... and not sure where to start.  I have added a variable in a saveText function to store the input text.  Any help or direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you should approach your problem step-by-step and ask about it here step-by-step. :)

Comment: I second that you should play around some more. Maybe in `jsfiddle.net`. Just set it up and try things.

Comment: I recently wrote an overview on JavaScript closures that may help: http://www.unleashed-technologies.com/blog/2010/09/07/how-closures-work-javascript-overview

Comment: Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PdHed/1/) to get you started. It's not much right now, but maybe you and the SO community can help it grow into what it needs to be while you learn a few things along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like http://jsfiddle.net/1nv151b13b0b/pWBdw/1/

Comment: Nice use of closure and in place execution.